# VHDL read bit from input problem

Tags: vhdl

```
entity TestRun01 is
    Port ( Clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Din : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Dout : out  STD_LOGIC_vector(11 downto 0));
end TestRun01;

architecture Behavioral of TestRun01 is
    signal regr : std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) :="000000000010"; 
    signal reg  : std_logic;
begin
    process(Clk,reg)
    begin
        if falling_edge(CLK) then
            if Din ='1' then
                reg <='1';
            elsif  Din='0' then
                reg <='0';
            else
                reg <= reg;
            end if;
            regr(0)<=reg;                   
            regr<=regr(10 downto 0) & '0';
        end if;
    end process;

    Dout<=regr;
end Behavioral;
```

[image: why only shift '0' to the shift register?]

why only shift '0' to the shift register?

if I change the code from

```
regr(0)<=reg;   
regr<=regr(10 downto 0) & '0';
```

to

```
regr<=regr(10 downto 0) & '0';
regr(0)<=reg;
```

the bench mark shows 
[image]

Comment: `process(Clk,reg)`: `reg` is not required: the fully synchronous process only has to trigger on `Clk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the following two lines of code:

```
regr(0)<=reg;                   
regr<=regr(10 downto 0) & '0';
```

Since `regr` has a width of 12 bits, the second line assigns every bit in this signal. Since the last assignment to a particular signal takes priority, your initial assignment to `regr(0)` is effectively ignored.

In the second example with the two lines swapped, the last assignment to `regr(0)<=reg;` takes priority over the assignment to `'0'` on the previous line.

The more readable version would look like this:

```
regr <= regr(10 downto 0) & reg;
```

thus performing the whole assignment in one line without potential for confusion.

In your second example, you are seeing `'U'` being shifted through, because your signal `reg` is not initialised. You could initialise your signal to `'0'` using:

```
signal reg : std_logic := '0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! why the  last assignment to a particular signal takes priority?

Comment: @YuanCao, it is part of the VHDL standard that the final assignment in a succession of assignments to a single destination takes priority.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement. See paragraph 8 rules 1) thru 5). Not so much 'takes priority' as deletes the old transactions from the projected output waveform.